# Qore streams in multi-threaded environment

Tags: qore

Qore stream documentation (https://qoretechnologies.com/manual/qorus/latest/qore/lang/html/class_qore_1_1_output_stream.html) says that stream instance cannot be called from other thread than the object has been created (and I really see hardcoded check snippet `if (tid != gettid()) then raise exception`. It seems rather as huge limitation because even locking won't help.

What is supposed solution when I need use a stream object from more threads ?

I can imagine extra "stream" thread and a queue as only solution.

Answer (score 2):

Iterators and streams both are limited to single-threaded use by design for performance reasons and also because no realistic use case for using streams from multiple threads could be identified with the built-in stream objects when the design and implementation of Qore streams was done.

You can implement your own streams that support multi-threaded use because the minimal internal C++ implementations of the abstract base classes, [InputStream](https://qoretechnologies.com/manual/qorus//current/qore/lang/html/class_qore_1_1_input_stream.html) and [OutputStream](https://qoretechnologies.com/manual/qorus//current/qore/lang/html/class_qore_1_1_output_stream.html), do not contain any limitations on multi-threaded usage.

If you really need multi-threaded support in builtin streams, then Qore could be extended to allow for the appropriate locking to be implemented in subclasses for example.